# How to keep the nested div appearing?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

This is my CSS code:

```
.elementor-post__text {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="elementor-post__card">
<div class="elementor-post__text">
<h4 class="elementor-post__title">
<a href="">Best<span class="dashicons "></span> </a>
</h4>
<div class="elementor-post__excerpt">
<p>As a beginner, you will surely encounter a lot of problems</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My question is: 
How to keep the "elementor-post__excerpt" appearing?
I wanna show "elementor-post__excerpt".
Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. Sorry for my English.

Comment: you can't hide the parent and then show the children, you need to hide the children that you don't want to show instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your `elementor-post__excerpt` div nested within the `elementor-post__text` div, and that div has its visibility hidden, so do all its children. In this case the div you want to be visible. You can try moving the excerpt div outside the div with the CSS class.